# Why is most of my RAM always being used?

Tags: ram, acer-z120

I got one of those phone boosters for Android but it looks like it does not work very well because when I run a clean it stops at 88% or somewhere and immediately tells me that I have to clean again.

I figured that it is some kind of bug or that an app is using a lot of RAM and it can't be cleaned.

Is there a way to clean more RAM so my phone can get faster?

Comment: What phone is this on?

Comment: check the title: the acer z120

Comment: Oops, my bad :P  I've personally found those phone boosters to be a load of hot air.  I've never noticed any change in performance with my phone after running them.  I would try running [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi&hl=en) to see what is using so much RAM.

Comment: and then how can I stop it using RAM

Comment: Well if you find out what application is using the ram the best option would be to uninstall it.

Comment: yeah but like 60% is used by android or system files. and the rest is just like using 3 mb per applications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18987/discussion-between-winseybash-and-codermaster).

Comment: no because I don't have a samsung galaxy s3

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, of these phone/RAM booster apps are nothing more than a custom version of the stock Running Apps option already in Android. Thus, they themselves take up more RAM while not offering very useful functionality.I would recommend against using them. I hope you didn't have to pay for this app. TIP:
I remember when I had a 512MB RAM phone Location services used to take up a lot of RAM. You can turn of all location services(GPS & Network based) when you don't need them.

Comment: I never use them exept mobile data sometimes so that might be it